# How to add a line from a list into another file when a specified line is found?

Tags: text-processing, xml

Basically I have 2 files. One has a list of router and switch login prompts, like this:

```
user@router1
user@router2
user@switch1
user@switch2
```

The other file has blocks of XML, like this:

```
<headTag>
    <anotherTag1>
    <anotherTag2>
    </anotherTag2>
    </anotherTag1>
</headTag>
<headTag>
    <anotherTag1>
    <anotherTag2>
    </anotherTag2>
    </anotherTag1>
</headTag>
```

So what I want to do is this, I need to loop though the XML file and each time it detects `<headTag>` place the next item on the router/switch list on the line above it, so the final output would end up like this:

```
user@router1
<headTag>
    <anotherTag1>
    <anotherTag2>
    </anotherTag2>
    </anotherTag1>
</headTag>
user@router2
<headTag>
    <anotherTag1>
    <anotherTag2>
    </anotherTag2>
    </anotherTag1>
</headTag>
```

How can I achieve this? I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server and have approximately 800 items in the router/switch list and the same number of XML blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here another short solution with [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and [`ed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29).

It modify the XML file *inplace*. Ignore the output to the console.

```
sed -e 's#.*#/<headTag>/i\n&\n.\n//\nw#' PATH_TO_LIST_FILE | ed PATH_TO_XML_FILE
```

The `sed` commands line writes following Ed commands for each line in the list file:

```
/<headTag>/i                # search for tag and insert before
user@router1                # text to insert (= the current line in the list file)
.                           # end of insert
//                          # skip current tag (we are now on the line above the current tag))
w                           # save (could be postponed to the end, but makes the command shorter...)
```

For this command it is needed that `<headTag>` is always at the beginning of a line in the xml file.

Comment: Please comment before down-voting.

Comment: I just tried this and the result was this repeatedly for each result:
`153528
?
?

?`

Comment: @Campino The command modify the xml directly. Ignore its output to the terminal. I added this hint now to the answer.

Comment: +1 Neat trick! I know this is rich coming from the guy who proposed a `perl` answer, but it feels a bit "write-only" :)

Comment: Oh... I see it now! That works great! I can't even upvote this because I don't have enough repuatation, but it is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
perl -MTie::File -e '
$xml_file_name="path_to_xml_file";
$list_file_name="path_to_list_file";
tie @xml_lines,"Tie::File",$xml_file_name;
tie @list_lines,"Tie::File",$list_file_name;
@offsets = grep {$xml_lines[$_]=~/\Q<headTag>\E/} (0..$#xml_lines);
@offsets=reverse @offsets;
splice @xml_lines,pop @offsets,0,pop @list_lines;'
```

**Diclaimer**

- This code will modify your XML file in place. Make a backup copy if you don't want the original clobbered.
- This code is **untested**. Backup both files before trying it.

**Edit**

Fixed a typo: note the added tilde `~` on line 6.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this on my personal Linux box at home before attempting in a production environment.

Comment: Always a good idea...